# why can't Bundle exec can't find installed gems in 'vendor/bundle'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to execute a rails project (via `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`) and I'm getting "Can't find GEM NAME" errors.
What's strange is that this is only a recent issue after a DB upgrade caused by an upgrade of the image the VM uses for running the app.

Whilst the image has been upgraded, none of the things directly related to the app itself (besides the DB upgrade) have actually changed, we're still currently using the same Ruby, same gems and version and same method of building the RPM (via FPM).

the `.bundle/config` is:

```yaml
---
BUNDLE_FROZEN: "true"
BUNDLE_PATH: "vendor/bundle"
```

and it's definitely being picked up by bundler as `bundle env` clearly shows:

````
## Bundler settings

\```
frozen
  Set for your local app (/var/app_name/current/.bundle/config): true
path
  Set for your local app (/var/app_name/current/.bundle/config): "vendor/bundle"
\```
````

the specific error I get is:

```
bundler: failed to load command: puma (/var/app_name/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/puma)
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-12.3.3 in any of the sources
```

but If I look in `vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems` I can clearly see rake & that it's the correct version.

I have noticed the gem path doesn't seem to include the vendor path:

````
## Environment

\```
Bundler       1.16.1
  Platforms   ruby, x86_64-linux
Ruby          2.5.9p229 (2021-04-05 revision 67939) [x86_64-linux]
  Full Path   /usr/bin/ruby
  Config Dir  /etc
RubyGems      2.7.6.3
  Gem Home    /usr/share/gems
  Gem Path    /var/app_name/.gem/ruby:/usr/share/gems:/usr/local/share/gems
  User Path   /var/app_name/.gem/ruby
  Bin Dir     /usr/bin
Tools
  Git         not installed
  RVM         not installed
  rbenv       not installed
  chruby      not installed
\```
````

I've tried changing that with `bundle config set --local path vendor/bundle` or  by doing `BUNDLE_PATH="vendor/bundle" bundle env` but see no difference in the Gem path.

I'm not sure what else to do to fix this as I've honestly never encountered this specific issue before of "bundler seemingly ignoring the vendor gems" so I'm kind of stuck

P.S. I know the ruby version is a bit old, I'll get around to upgrading at some point...

Comment: In your project do you have `bin/bundle` or `bin/bundler`?

Comment: `$ ls bin/`
`bundle  rails  rake  setup  spring  update  yarn`. EDIT: I think I see where you're going with this, let me check something. FURTHER EDIT: No, using `./bin/bundle` had no effect :(

Comment: I also noticed, when I run `bundle install --path vendor/bundle` it seems to think that the gems aren't installed in the vendor directory and tries to install them (which fails as the dev dependencies aren't available on the test server). Could be related?

Comment: `$ ./bin/bundle install --local --path vendor/bundle/
Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.16.1) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.17.3). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
Could not find racc-1.6.0 in any of the sources` but I can definitely see `racc` if I do `ls vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems`